# PlacesService and the need of html node

Tags: google-maps, licensing, google-places-api

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&amp;libraries=places&language=pt-PT" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function initialize() {
                var request = {
                    placeId: 'ChIJO_PkYRozGQ0R0DaQ5L3rAAQ'
                };

                service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(document.getElementById('places'));
                service.getDetails(request, callback);

                function callback(place, status) {
                    if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
                        console.log(place);
                    }
                }
            }
            google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>  <div id="places"></div> </body>

</html>
```

I have this code that works well, but i don't know why i need to use

```
PlacesService(document.getElementById('some id'));
```

If i use only `PlacesService();` I will get an error. The html_attributions is none: `html_attributions: Array[0]length: 0`

So, is my code fine, or what should I do?

http://jsfiddle.net/c6p14g4d/

Answer (score 7):

(If you haven't figured it out 6 months later) Your code will work and [should adhere to Google's policies surrounding the PlacesService](https://developers.google.com/places/webservice/policies).

From my understanding, "attributions" are some sort of information attributing the source of the information to a particular partner, for example, a review from Yelp (I don't know if they partner with Yelp, but that's the idea). Obviously the partner wants the end consumer of the information to know who provided it.

The idea is that when you perform a search with the PlacesService, if there is an attached map, it will render "attributions" automatically. Thus, if you don't have a map, the library will attempt to render the attributions into an html node. Hiding that node (or the map) is against the policy.

It's important to note that the `html_attributions` array might not always be empty in all cases when using the library, but as long as you provide a *visible* node in the DOM, you're fine, since the library automatically populates the node with attributions if they are there.

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#PlacesService), that needs to be either a HTMLDivElement or a Map:

```
Constructor                                     Description
PlacesService(attrContainer:HTMLDivElement|Map) Creates a new instance of the PlacesService that renders attributions in the specified container.
```

Comment: this mean what? that I can use the code above, with an empty div?

Comment: my question is about the licence attribution. Since i am not using a map, only the city name, and the html_attributions is an empty array, what is the correct way to handle this situation.