# Not able to use the google textsearch in place api

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I want to  use the textSearch method from google place library api without the maps.I have the longitude,latitude,place's name which I want to search.Now I just want to send the request to  google and use the results.I have included the script

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?&libraries=places"></script>
```

But I now have to use the PlaceService and for that I think I need to include maps in my app which I don't want.

```
var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
service.textSearch(request, callback);
```

I just need to search the place with longitude,latitude and radius.I have try making the request directly by generating the url and sending the ajax request.But it return

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource
```

How do I search the text in my ember app ?

Comment: related question: [PlacesService and the need of html node](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27990005/placesservice-and-the-need-of-html-node)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the Places-Library does not require a map.

When you print results(without a map) you must:

1. display  the google-logo: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#LogoRequirements
2. Print the attributions(if there are any) . Therefore you must supply a Node as argument for `PlacesService`

```js
service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(
  document.getElementById('attributions')//attributions-container
);

//send a query
service.textSearch({query:'Stackoverflow'}, function(results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
      var item=document.createElement('li');
      item.appendChild(document.createTextNode(results[i].name));
      document.getElementById('results').appendChild(item);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&libraries=places"></script>
<strong>Search for &quot;Stackoverflow&quot; </strong><br/>

<!-- google-logo -->
<img src="http://developers.google.com/places/documentation/images/powered-by-google-on-white.png"/>

<ul id="results"></ul>

<!-- attributions-container -->
<div id="attributions" style="background:#f1f1f1">
  You'll see here the attributions when there are any
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The [PlaceService constuctor](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#PlacesService) takes either a `google.Maps.Map` object or a HTML div (it doesn't_have_ to be a map, but there has to be a place for it to display warnings, etc.)

> PlacesService(attrContainer:**HTMLDivElement**|Map)   Creates a new instance of the PlacesService that renders attributions in the specified container.

Comment: Can you Please elaborate I am very new to the whole frontend thing